# Programmatically apply a theme so that it will apply to control attributes that have NOT already been defined

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am studying for the Microsoft exam for web developers (asp.net 4.0) and I came across this question:

> You need to programmatically apply a theme named Fabrikam so that it will apply to control attributes that have NOT already been defined. In other words, you do NOT want the theme to override control attributes. Which of the following code samples does this correctly?

(A)

```
void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

this.StyleSheetTheme = "Fabrikam";

}
```

(B)

```
public override String StyleSheetTheme

{ get { return "Fabrikam"; }

}*
```

Option B is chosen as the anwser.

Why can't option A be the answer, StyleSheetTheme won't override control attributes?

Comment: is this the complete question they asked, or you are missing something about applying StyleSheetTheme property given in (B) ?

Answer (score 0):

It is the page_init event where themes applied to the controls

Each control is first created with the attributes set in the .aspx markup and then assigned the settings stored in the theme file. In this way, theme settings override corresponding markup settings. Unthemed properties retain the original value set in the .aspx file.

So If you don't assign theme in Page_Init they will not get precedence and will not override the existing control attributes.

Comment: so why was option B chosen ,not A?